# Як перекласти з англійської "Further reading"

Tags: from-english

Як перекласти з англійської "Further reading" (у значення додаткові джерела, як от у англомовних статтях Вікіпедії є розділ "Further reading"). Цей вираз повинен бути досить універсальним: його можна буде використовувати і в енциклопедіях (позначка відповідного розділу) і в наукових працях / research papers (позначка розділу в кінці праці) тощо.

В інтернеті зустрічав варіанти перекладу:

- Подальше читання
- Рекомендована література
- Література для подальшого читання

Хотілося б почути чи є якийсь вдалий український варіант (підкріплений джерелами) можливо навіть новотвір. Бажано дійсно вдалий варіант перекладу, а не просто вираз "Література" (навіть не "рекомендована література") як це прийнято було писати в радянських наукових працях і який зараз вживають багато українських науковців. Вираз "література" у цьому контексті - ні в які ворота (це як написати "Literature" англійською у цьому контексті - сенсу ніякого)

Comment: Я перекладаю як *дальше читання*. І чому література в цьому контексті не підходить - незрозуміло, адже література буває не тільки художньою.

Comment: В [українських статтях Вікіпедії](https://www.google.com.ua/search?q=%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%88%D0%B5+%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8F&oq=%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%88%D0%B5+%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8F&aqs=chrome..69i57.7220j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) перевага надається варіанту *подальше читання*.

Comment: Я завжди перекладаю як «Читати далі» або «Читати ще» :)

Comment: Хмм, 90 очок bounty полетіли на вітер. Так ніхто й не запропонував більш розлогу відповідь...

Comment: @OksanaGubrenko щодо "Подальше читання" то згоден що в укрвікі часто вживають саме цей варіант для "Further reading", але от у самих правилах у них прописано "«Рекомендована література», «Додаткова література» та «Додаткова інформація» (https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D1%96%D0%BA%D1%96%D0%BF%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%96%D1%8F:%D0%A1%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C/%D0%A1%D1%82%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%83%D1%80%D0%B0_%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%82%D1%96#%D0%A0%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B0_%D0%BB%D1%96%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%83%D1%80%D0%B0)

Answer (score 3):

У неформальному контексті — [*чтиво*](http://sum.in.ua/s/chtyvo)

Існує [онлайн-бібліотека](http://chtyvo.org.ua/) з такою назвою.

Навіть у нас на сайті це слово [використовувалося](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/search?q=%D1%87%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BE).

Comment: Непоганий варіант.